# Firebase: Deleting instance token via admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have a web app with a known registration token / instance ID.
I can send messages to it via a node script, implemented using the Firebase admin SDK.

I'd like to delete / revoke the registration token / instance ID of the client, but I'm struggling to find out how to achieve this.

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.instanceId.InstanceId.html#deleteinstanceid) mention a method (deleteInstanceId) which sounds like it could be used for this purpose, but trying the following returns an error.

```
admin.instanceId().deleteInstanceId(<the client token>)

// UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Instance ID "<the client token>": Malformed instance ID argument.
```

I also tried this approach, from this [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/manage-iids#delete_an_id_with_a_server_api_call).

```
admin.instanceId().deleteInstanceId(<the client token>);

// UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Instance ID "<the client token>": Malformed instance ID argument.
```

(Context: For GDPR sake, we want to programmatically remove known device tokens for users who were asked to be deleted from our system)

Comment: How did you obtain the instance ID string? You might be passing an FCM registration token instead of the instance ID string.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Hiranya. I'm passing the registration token of the client I'd like to delete, as in the same token I use to target messages to a specific device when publishing a message via the admin SDK.
Addording to this page (https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#examples_of_end-user_personal_data_processed_by_firebase), "Firebase Cloud Messaging uses Instance IDs to determine which devices to deliver messages to.".
My understanding is that in their words, the instance ID is the registration token. Is that not correct?

Comment: I believe they are different things. Notice how the [`InstanceIdResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/InstanceIdResult.html) on Android has separate `getId()` and `getToken()` methods. You need to pass the former to `deleteInstanceId()`, but you're currently using the latter.

Comment: what you say makes sense, but I can't find the documentation of how to achieve that, using the Node.js Client package. Am I blind, or is it to be achieved somehow else? :)

Comment: Instance IDs are only assigned to Android and IOS devices, so they are only exposed in the respective mobile SDKs. So you need to somehow get those app instances to send their Instance ID with your server-side code.

Comment: That's it, mystery solved! Thanks for the clarification :)